# How Can I Suppress Warnings in Python Module CppHeaderParser

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### How Do I Change the Value of  a Variable or Function in a Foreign Module?

I have a C++ header file that I need to parse. I'm using [CppHeaderParser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CppHeaderParser/). Sadly, the header generates a lot of warnings that I'd like to suppress. The header in question is maintained by someone else, so I can't just fix it and be done.

CppHeaderParser doesn't include a *configurable* way to suppress warnings, but it is controlled by a variable and a function in the module

```
# Controls warning_print
print_warnings = 1

...

def warning_print(arg):
    if print_warnings: print(("[%4d] %s"%(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno, arg)))
```

In my script, I tried changing the value of `print_warnings`:

```
import CppHeaderParser
CppHeaderParser.print_warnings = 0
cpp_info = CppHeaderParser.CppHeader(my_h_file)
```

But this had no effect.
How do I set a variable in a different module such that a class defined in that module will see it?

In my case, I might also like to redefine `warning_print` to examine the warnings and skip only the specific warnings I wish to ignore. I encountered the same problem as setting `print_warnings`. The assignment "worked" but had no effect, as if the code in CppHeaderParser wasn't looking at the values I set.

**Note**: I have worked around the problem by making a temp copy of the header file, correcting the problems, but I consider this a fragile solution.

**Update**: I was able to completely and unintelligently suppress all the warnings with:

```
CppHeaderParser.CppHeaderParser.print_warnings = 0
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, It's not actually a Python warning. The module does it's own "warning" about the contents of the C++ header contents.

Comment: I didn't know whether to title the question based on what I was actually trying to accomplish (CppHeaderParser behavior) or what I considered to be the underlying issue (changing athe value of a module local variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked the source. The problem with your method is that in CppHeaderParser file there are import with *:

```
from .CppHeaderParser import *
```

So you need to change the way you import CppHeaderParser class:

```
from CppHeaderParser import CppHeaderParser
```

It should work.

Finally, just try this:

```
from CppHeaderParser import CppHeaderParser
CppHeaderParser.print_warnings = 0
cpp_info = CppHeaderParser.CppHeader(my_h_file)
```

**The reason of such a behaviour is that `from` statement creates the copy of variable from imported module but not an alias**. I will try to explain it on a simple example. Let's suppose we have some module named `import_test` with the following contents:

```
foo = "Init value"

def f():
    print(foo)
```

Then execute the following code:

```
>> from import_test import *
>> f()
Init value
>> foo = "Updated value"
>> f()
Init value
```

The reason is that you change the copy of variable `foo` so the actual value of `import_test.foo` variable is not changed.

But we have a different behaviour when we import the module itself:

```
>> import import_test
>> import_test.f()
Init value
>> import_test.foo = "Updated value"
>> import_test.f()
Updated value
```

So in the case of `CppHeaderParser` package when you make `import CppHeaderParser` the code inside `CppHeaderParser.__init__` is executed. And python interpreter creates a copy of `warnings_print` variable inside a CppHeaderParser. But to change the behaviour of a `print_warning` function you have to change the value of `CppHeaderParser.CppHeaderParser.warnings_print`.

Comment: I tried this, too (though I don't know why it would be different). Same behavior. It took no notice of my assignment. If I change the value in the file, it has an effect, but not this way.

Comment: This seems to work. Can you update your answer with an explanation of _why_ it works or what it accomplishes that not doing the import this way doesn't do? How is `CppHeaderParser.CppHeaderParser.print_warnings` different than `CppHeaderParser.print_warnings`?

Answer (score 0):

Try monkey patching:

```
import CppHeaderParser

def my_silent_warning_print(arg):
    pass

CppHeaderParser.warning_print = my_silent_warning_print
```

Comment: I tried redefining the function as well as changing the variable in this way. It didn't affect what the module did.